# Hard-code encoded query in results

Tags: low-search

How can one encode the search query to hard-code it in the results tag?

I would like to have a "related content" section on a page whereby the related content is gathered by low search.

The keywords are based on the entry `title` of the entry the related content is shown on.
At the moment i'm embedding the related content section and passing the `{title}` to the embed.
I would like to use the `{title}` as search query.

If 'Encode query' is set to 'yes', this does not work, because the query is not encoded (if set to no, it works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the `keywords` parameter on the `results` tag and omit the `query` parameter.

```
{exp:low_search:results keywords="{embed:title}"}
```